# Como liberar o scrolling no Safari 11.1?

Tags: javascript, safari, ipad, mobile-safari

Precisei fazer isso para que o conteúdo não fique sendo remexido e fazendo swipe com o dedo, só que agora o scrolling da página parou de funcionar, como faço para liberar o rolamento?

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}, { passive: false });
```

Comment: Já tentou aplicar esse evento apenas na div específica em vez do `document` todo, algo como: `document.querySelector("SELETOR").addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {`?

Comment: já, não deu muito certo.